# Flutter : Show BottomNavigationBar conditionally

Tags: flutter

How to show BottomNavigationBar conditionally

Comment: Please see: [Asking Questions - Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Answer: You can't do a ternary operator without the `else` case.

Comment: So, what should I do if I just need to use if() condition alone in flutter widget?

Comment: If you tell us your use-case we might be able to help you.

Comment: then just write `if (myExpression == True) return True;`

Comment: it doesn't work like that in flutter widgets

Comment: See my answer with the code-snippet.

Comment: @AnitS Use `condition ? Widget() : null`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To show a BottomNavBar conditionally**, you can check for your condition and if its true then give the `bottomNavigationBar` field its properties, otherwise give it a null.

```
bottomNavigationBar: conditionTrue ? BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            ),
            title: Text('One'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            ),
            title: Text('Two'),
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            ),
            title: Text('Three'),
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        showSelectedLabels: true,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        selectedFontSize: 16,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
      ) : null, //give it a null if the condition is not met...
```

**If you want to hide BottomNavigationBarItem conditionally:**

Step 1: Define a list that contains the BottomNavigationBarItems that you want to show initially as:

```
List<BottomNavigationBarItem> items = <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      // icon: Icon(null),
      icon: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      ),
      title: Text('One'),
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      ),
      title: Text('Two'),
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      ),
      title: Text('Three'),
    ),
  ];
```

Step 2: Pass this items list as an argument to the items parameter in the BottomNavigationBar constructor as:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar( //remove the const keyword from here in your code too.
        items: items,
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
        showSelectedLabels: true,
        showUnselectedLabels: true,
        selectedFontSize: 16,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
      ),
```

Step 3: Set the state of items list anywhere in your code to change the items in the list.

For the demonstration purpose, I am changing the state whenever you tap on the Floating action button. You can implement such functionality anywhere in your code.

```
floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            items.removeAt(0);
          });
        },
```

Comment: Well, kind of. I need to show a particular bottom navigation drawer item only when a condition is true, else it should be hidden. But if I follow this answer, I can make it invisible by providing title and icon to null or transparent, but not hidden.

Comment: Sorry but that's not what I meant. Suppose I want to hide ```BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            ),
            title: Text('Three'),
          ),``` if a condition is true

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a Ternary operator without the `else` case.

Since the Ternary operator consists of `?:` you can't opt out of using one or the other.

Question from OP: *"So, what should I do if I just need to use if() condition alone?"*

Simply do:

```
Widget _someWidget() {
  if (condition) {
    return doSomething
  }
  return doSomethingElse
}
```

Depending on what you want to do, you can use a ternary operator like this:

```
condition ? doSomething : null
```

Comment: Usually that works but can't use `null` here in my case

Comment: Them use the other example i provided

Comment: @legacyO7 you can use a `Container` or `SizedBox` of height 0 whenever a non-null value is mandatory.